# PHP include function - nested lists

Tags: php, list, include, nested

I'm using the include function as a way to prevent me having to update my top menu on every one of my pages when I make a change. Here is the snippet using include function on my site:-

```
<div id ="header">
   <div id="logo"></div>
     <nav>
        <?php include 'menu.php' ?>
     </nav>
</header>
```

And here is what the menu.php file holds

```
    <div id="menu_container">
      <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
        <li><a href="badmintonIndex.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="badmintonAbout.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Leagues</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Brighton</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Singles</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badmintonSinglestables.php">Tables</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Doubles</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tables</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="badmintonRules.php">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hall of Fame</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Brighton</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="badmintonFame.php">Singles</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="badmintonContact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

However my problem is that the menu items that include nested items, that will drop down and offer more options when you hover over them, aren't working this way. But they do work correctly when I copy the code in directly.

Here at the pages where the code is copied in directly and works and where I'm using include and it doesn't work:-

Working [dtlsports.co.uk/badmintonSinglestables.php](http://dtlsports.co.uk/badmintonSinglestables.php)

Not working [dtlsports.co.uk/badmintonSinglestablesA.php](http://dtlsports.co.uk/badmintonSinglestablesA.php)

As you can see, the navigation menu on the first page works, but it doesn't drop down properly on the second page

Is there anything anyone can suggest? Thanks!

Comment: when you "copy them in directly" are you still putting them inside that `<nav>` tag?

Comment: Can we see the working version (preferably in action) please? Maybe just pastebin it somewhere

Comment: Actually, are all the php files in the same directory? Maybe the first one (containing the <div id ="header">) is included by another PHP script?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses! Yes I am putting the nav tags round correctly when I copy it in directly, and it seems to work fine that way. All the php files are in the same directory except the styles.css file which is in another folder. This is also the first time I am using the include function on my website.

Comment: Here at the pages where the code is copied in directly and works and where I'm using include and it doesn't work:-

Working
http://dtlsports.co.uk/badmintonSinglestables.php

Not working
http://dtlsports.co.uk/badmintonSinglestablesA.php

As you can see, the navigation menu on the first page works, but it doesn't drop down properly on the second page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on the non working page you are not including al js scripts that you have on the working page. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
$('.top').click(function() {$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast'); return false;});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was just about to give that exact same answer :)

Comment: :-) I spotted the problem opening the two pages side by side and inspecting them with firebug.

Comment: Fantastic!! Working perfectly! Thanks everyone who helped out, this is going to save me so much time in the long run :-)